# Gradient of a multi-dimensional multi-variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

(First of all, feel free to suggest a better title for the question, I might just be totally missing the naming, hence not finding my answer because of that :) )

I understand how to compute the partial derivative of some function $f(x, y)$, with respect its different variables, and how to get the gradient of the function from that.

Now, if I have a function $f$ that takes, let say, two 2D vectors $p1$ and $p2$ as inputs and I want to find the gradient of this function with respect to each point $\nabla_{p1}f(p1, p2)$ and $\nabla_{p2}f(p1, p2)$. This is where I'm totally lost. How is this computed ?

For example, if $f(p1,p2) = |p1 - p2| - d$, $|p1 - p2|$ being the distance between the two points (or the norm of the vector defined by those points) and $d$ being a constant, how does one compute $\nabla_{p1}f(p1, p2)$ and $\nabla_{p2}f(p1, p2)$ ?

In that case, the results I need to find are
$$\nabla_{p1}f(p1, p2) = \frac{p1-p2}{|p1 - p2|}$$
and
$$\nabla_{p2}f(p1, p2) = -\frac{p1-p2}{|p1 - p2|}$$
but I do not understand how to find this result.

Edit:
To add a bit more context, I want to understand how to compute those formulas to be able to put them in a computer graphics physics simulation loop (namely using [Position-Based Dynamics](https://matthias-research.github.io/pages/publications/posBasedDyn.pdf)).
The function $f$ is in fact a *constraint* between the inputs (in that case, we want the two points to keep a certain distance from each other).

Comment: Have a look at the notion of [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

Comment: That notation seems to be the directional derivative. The gradient of a scalar function $F:U\subseteq \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is simply the vector $$\nabla F(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\bigg(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_1},\dots,\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_n}\bigg).$$

Comment: @Vajra As far as I understand, the directional derivative is giving derivative along a vector of inputs, but you have as many elements in the vector as you have variables in your function, and it is computed using the dot product between this vector and the gradient of the function.
In my case, I'm looking for the gradient of the function with respect to an input in the function, this input being a vector (2d or 3d in that case).

Comment: I've added the solutions I'm looking for, if it can help making my problem clearer

Comment: @Miguel I'm not sure I understand how to use this in my case. As far as I understand, I would need to write my function as a vector of functions and I then can deduce a matrix which contains the partial derivatives of each "subfunction" with respect to each input of my function. But, I don't really see how I would write my function as a vector in my case, and, as far as I understand, the jacobian is more an analysis tool for the function, giving info at some point, when what I'm asking for is how to compute the function gradients in the "general case". But maybe I'm totally missing the point.

Comment: @null Could you elaborate on how to use this to compute the $\nabla_{p1}f$ and $\nabla_{p2}f$ formulas in an answer please ? The idea is to be able to plug this in a computer graphics physics simulation loop, and I would like to understand how to compute it on a known answer, to extrapolate on other formulas (with more variables) for which I do not know the solution.

Comment: Computation-wise i think it is convenient to use differentials:
$$df(p_1,p_2)=d[\sqrt{(p_1-p_2)\cdot(p_1-p_2)}-d]=\frac{1}{2|p_1-p_2|}d[(p_1-p_2)\cdot(p_1-p_2)]=\frac{1}{2|p_1-p_2|}[(dp_1-dp_2)\cdot(p_1-p_2)+(p_1-p_2)\cdot(dp_1-dp_2)]=\frac{p_1-p_2}{|p_1-p_2|}\cdot dp_1+\frac{-(p_1-p_2)}{|p_1-p_2|}\cdot dp_2$$
Where $\cdot$ is a dot product. The gradients wrt variables are the things multiplied by the respective differentials then. I can elaborate if you need.

Comment: @Koncopd I think I kinda get it using this approach, can you make this an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comment. You can use the calculus of differentials for this kind of calculations. My favorite tutorial on this is [Practical Guide to Matrix Calculus for Deep Learning by Andrew Delong](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.304.5533). It is about the use of differentials for matrices, but of course it also can be used for vectors. Rule **(17)** in the paper is exactly about your question.
$$dy=\sum_kA^k\cdot dX^k \rightarrow \nabla_ky=A^k$$
so applying the rule to your example
$$df=d(\sqrt{(p_1-p_2)\cdot(p_1-p_2)}-d)=\text{by (15)}=\frac{1}{2|p_1-p_2|}d[(p_1-p_2)\cdot(p_1-p_2)]=$$
$$=\text{by (13)}=\frac{1}{2|p_1-p_2|}[d(p_1-p_2)\cdot(p_1-p_2)+(p_1-p_2)\cdot d(p_1-p_2)]=$$
$$=\text{by (11)}=\frac{1}{2|p_1-p_2|}[(dp_1-dp_2)\cdot(p_1-p_2)+(p_1-p_2)\cdot (dp_1-dp_2)]=$$
$$=\frac{p_1-p_2}{|p_1-p_2|}\cdot dp_1+\frac{-(p_1-p_2)}{|p_1-p_2|}\cdot dp_2$$
So by the rule **(17)**:
$$\nabla_{p_1}f=\frac{p_1-p_2}{|p_1-p_2|},\ \nabla_{p_2}f=\frac{-(p_1-p_2)}{|p_1-p_2|}$$
In order to learn the theory behind the differentials, you can read, for example, the book  "Matrix Differential Calculus with Applications in Statistics and Econometrics" by J. Magnus et al.

Comment: For some reason the link seems to be dead, here is a webarchive link : https://web.archive.org/web/20180127130543/http://www.psi.toronto.edu/~andrew/papers/matrix_calculus_for_learning.pdf

Answer (score 0):

We are given
$$ f(x,y) := |x-y|-d$$

1. $f$ is not actually differentiable everywhere. It is not differentiable on the set $x=y$.
2. Note that $$f(x,y)=f(y,x).\tag{$*$}$$ So in fact, $(\nabla_y f)(a,b) = (\nabla_x f)(b,a)$. Easy to verify by checking the directional derivatives:
   $$ (\partial_{y_i} f)(a,b) = \lim_{t\downarrow 0} \frac{f(a,b+te_i)-f(a,b)}t\overset{ (*)}= \lim_{t\downarrow 0} \frac{f(b+te_i,a)-f(b,a)}t= (\partial_{x_i} f)(b,a).$$
   Once we know this, we only need to compute one of them, say $\nabla_x f(x,y)$.
3. Lets consider $y$ as a fixed vector. Then $f$ is the composition of two functions $f=g\circ h$
   \begin{align} g&:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R &g(z) &:= |z|-d\\
   h&:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n &h(x) &:= x-y
   \end{align}
   and chain rule gives
   $$ \nabla_x f(x,y)^T = \nabla g(h(x))^T \nabla h(x)$$
4. The derivatives are
   $$ \nabla g(z) = \frac z{|z|}, \ (z\neq 0), \quad \nabla h(x) = I$$
5. putting it together
   $$  \nabla_x f(x,y)^T = \nabla g(h(x))^T \nabla h(x) = \frac{h(x)^TI}{|h(x)|} = \frac{(x-y)^T}{|x-y|}$$
   taking transposes gives the answer.